# How do I write VBA code that will allow me to jump from cell to cell as I hit the enter key

Tags: excel, vba

I have to do a lot of repetitive and I'm trying to automate things as rough as possible.  Let say I want to do the following:

1. Enter an integer in cell F2 hit enter and have the cursor jump to cell F9
2. Enter an integer in cell F9 hit enter and have the cursor jump to cell F15
3. Enter an integer in cell F15 hit enter and have the cursor jump to cell F21

I created the following code in the WorkSheet Module:

```
    Dim OldAddress As String ____________________________________________________________

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If OldAddress = Range("F2").Address Then
    Range("F9").Select
    ElseIf OldAddress = Range("F9").Address Then
    Range("F15").Select
ElseIf OldAddress = Range("F15").Address Then
    Range("F21").Select
    Else
    OldAddress = ActiveCell.Address
    End If
    End Sub
```

When I enter data in cell F2 and click Enter the Cursor jumps to cell F9, but then it seems to get stuck there.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the change event like that

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rg As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    Set rg = Union(Range("F2"), Range("F9"), Range("F15"), Range("F21"))

    If Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$F$2"
        Range("F9").Select
    Case "$F$9"
        Range("F15").Select
    Case "$F$15"
        Range("F21").Select
    End Select

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this test for the integer being added? Probably worth telliing OP why their method was doomed to fail i.e. even with correct syntax it would have propogated to the end cell F21 due to the nature of the event.

Comment: It does not test the input, i.e. you can enter any string and the cursor will move. Of course, you could easily add this tunctionality. Question then is what is the expected behaviour of the script in such a case. Should the cursor move to the next cell, should the script clear the input and stay at the cell.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a different event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim F2 As Range, F9 As Range, F15 As Range, F22 As Range
    Set F2 = Range("F2")
    Set F9 = Range("F9")
    Set F15 = Range("F15")
    Set F21 = Range("F21")

    If Not Intersect(Target, F2) Is Nothing Then
            F9.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, F9) Is Nothing Then
        F15.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, F15) Is Nothing Then
        F21.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```